# how to build ndk application?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

hi how to build ndk application...now i am using linux os and i am new for android application please tell me simply....

Comment: Why do you want to build application using NDK? Why not the SDK?

Comment: GO here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html   read the section "When to Develop in Native Code", if you understand everything and your idea falls in this category, go for NDK. Otherwise, use SDK.

Comment: now i am create one game project...so i want to build application in ndk

Comment: Thre's a reason to make your game in native? Maybe the SDK can work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't just jump right into the NDK - familiarize yourself with the SDK and have a play with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should hopefully help you out:

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Using_NDK_r4_with_the_Android_SDK_in_Netbeans

Shows you how to build a simple 'Hello World' app using the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the NDK will not let you build applications. It will only let you build a shared library object (`.so`) that your SDK application will open at runtime in order to execute native code.

Instead of the standard way to build and install applications:

```
ant compile    # (or ant debug)
ant install
```

You will have an extra step:

```
ndk-build      # builds the .so files
ant compile    # builds the Java app and embeds the .so within the final .apk
ant install
```