# Android and Java's JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm starting to learn java's JNI to use with an android device.

As I read somewhere, you must have some "glue" for the C++ part in order to be loaded through JNI.

My question is: Is it posible to have a run() function in C with the glue for JNI having that running the real app and having java only for the entry point?
Because I don't know if when invoking that run() function through JNI it may cause problems if that function calls another functions and so on.
Thanks for the tip!

EDIT: I want to code in C++ using ndk and trying to avoid coding in java. thus, I wanted to know if a) if I can compile and run in native with ndk or b) if i can use java only to invoke my app, example: calling woth jni something like app->run() and let it do all stuff instead of java. then, java will act only as an entry point.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you wish to achieve can you break it down into a high level overview as to what you want to achieve using the JNI?

Comment: i editted the original post to clarify it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you want to use java?

Comment: Don't want to use Java because I don't like it (and because I don't know it very well either).

Comment: You can use your C++ code to run calculations and do the background stuff but you will need to use Java to start the application and for creating the UI through activities following the Activity and Application life cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop for Android in C/C++ (no Java) **AND** you target newer devices (Gingerbread, android-9 app platform onwards) consider using NativeActivity.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html and folder inside NDK package `$NDK/docs/NATIVE-ACTIVITY.HTML` together with the sample code `$NDK/samples/native-activity`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that is somehow the thing I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a step-by-step howto in the following post: [How to create dll using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656500/how-to-create-dll-using-android/8657239#8657239) You can read it and put questions if you don't understand something.