# NDK in JAVA (building problems)

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native

I am trying to connect Unity with simple Java android development and I actually succeeded to get to the part where I can import unity project to android and if needed start it up.

The problem I am facing at the moment is how to pass variables back and forth between those 2 platforms. I found some tutorials and they all suggest to use Android NDK. I am new in this field and got some problems while getting it to work.

I followed this [tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html) and got stuck on building the application. I have my Android.mk file but when I run make (make app=ndk-demo) it throws an exception:

```
"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."
```

My Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk-demo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have 3 activities in my project, one .h and one .c files. I don't know whether I should include them or all-subdir-java-files does it for me.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is to build a shared library and import it to Unity for use. In this case I should be able to call methods from Unity to Java and other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656500/how-to-create-dll-using-android/8657239#8657239) question I've described step-by-step instructions how to make a native project. Hope this help you.